# plotting timeseries with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, timestamp

I have a data df that includes column of user ID, hour of website visit, day in a week and a timestamp.

```
   Userid  hour weekdays    timestamp
   "130"  "17" "Monday"    "140723" 
   "130"  "21" "Tuesday"   "156540" 
   "130"  "6"  "Sunday"    "211667" 
   "130"  "4"  "Monday"    "223738"
```

My goal is to produce plot similar to the following example:
[image]

I tried to generate normal ggplot but the hours on y axis are not ordered and dots don't appear.

**[EDIT]**
My code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=df$created_at,y=df$hour))+
  geom_line( data = df[df$id=="130",], aes( x=as.Date(data$created_at),y=(data$hour)), color="red")+
  geom_line( data = df[df$id=="220",], aes( x=as.Date(data$created_at),y=(data$hour)), color="blue")
```

Comment: You should post the `ggplot` code you wrote so that it will be easier to assess what's not working

Comment: What is the format of your `timestamp`? Year, month, date?

Comment: It looks like this: `2017-04-26 05:23:27.264781+00`